# How display watchkit glance from iOS app

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, apple-watch-glances

I have an iOS app with a corresponding WatchKit app.  When I press a button in the iOS app, I want to launch the watch app glance screen and show a countdown timer.

Which method or techniques should I use. I have already setup the glance screen and glance schemes, but have no idea how to launch the glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't programmatically launch your glance (or watch app) from your iOS app.

The best you can do is send the application context to the watch, so that the glance or watch app would already have details about the countdown, if either were opened by the user.

You can find out more about this in [WCSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html).